# Unable to to use Jenkins API tokens with wget

Tags: curl, jenkins, wget

Something really weird is happening regarding performing HTTP calls to a private Jenkins instance (using GitHub authentication).

curl works: `curl -u myuser:mytoken https://jenkins.example.com` or via `curl https://myser:mytoken@jenkins.example.com`

Doing the same with wget does not work, giving:
`HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden`

Note: `wget --http-user=<user> --http-password=<token> <url>` is the alternative syntax for wget, but both approaches to give the same results: 403.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try adding the `--auth-no-challenge` option to the `wget` command line.

Comment: Indeed, this fixed the issue. Now my question would be why is this needed for wget? Should I expect to see something like this needed for other clients too?

Comment: Is there a way to configure Jenkins (with Nginx in front of it) in such way that this additional parameter will not be needed?

Comment: Also raise it as as bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37055

Comment: `wget` by default only sends credentials when challenged (especially with basically plaintext passwords in basic auth that's a good idea : ). I _think_ that Jenkins does not support basic auth challenges at all, so there's no way around that option. You may use an older version of `wget` which does not have this security feature yet, though.

Comment: Came back to this after a year again, thanks again, very weird behavior by wget